# Error: Compiling Boost with MPI Support in Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, mpi, point-cloud-library

I am trying to compile a 64 bit version of Boost 1.57 (www.boost.org) from source with MPI support using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, but I am having errors.  I am following the directions on the following website (https://gist.github.com/UnaNancyOwen/d879a41710e9c05025f8#file-boost1-56-0-md).  I have followed the instructions to the letter, but I am (instead) running the following command to build:

```
C:\boost_1_57_0>b2.exe toolset = msvc-14.0 address-model = 64 --build-dir = build \ x64 install --prefix = "C: \ Program Files \ Boost" -j4
```

With the following error:

```
C:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src/tools\mpi.jam:251: syntax error at argument $(cluster_pack_path_native)
C:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src/tools\mpi.jam:252: syntax error at keyword {
libs\graph_parallel\build\Jamfile.v2:17: in modules.load
ERROR: rule "mpi.configured" unknown in module "Jamfile<C:\boost_1_57_0\libs\graph_parallel\build>".
C:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:311: in load-jamfile
C:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:64: in load
C:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:89: in load-used-projects
C:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:75: in load
C:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:145: in project.find
C:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:535: in load
C:\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:289: in import
C:\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
C:\boost_1_57_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

Any thoughts?  The goal is to get the C++ Point Cloud Library (PCL) to work for VS 2015.  I have Windows 8.  Let me know if you need any more details...